# Calculation for output that displays $1 per $1000 of amount from another column

Tags: 2013, list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I have a list that is a Sales Log.  I have  been tasked with creating a column that will look at a dollar amount and will give me a dollar amount based on that.  Specifically, $1 per $1000.

I am not wise in the ways of the formula lingo.  Anybody able to throw me a bone on this one.  I understand that there will be two columns, 1 with the inputted amount, the second will look at that, and base the "payout" based on full thousands, no rounding.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: To make sure I have the right idea: $1543 input, would get $1 output?

Comment: How would you do it in Excel? Start from there, most Excel functions have SharePoint equivalants most often even the same lingo.

Answer (score 0):

```
=ROUNDDOWN(amount/1000,0)
```

Help with formulas : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862071(v=office.14).aspx

As Danny stated, most basic functions in Excel are working in a calculated column in SharePoint.

Comment: That Microsoft documentation is plain wrong in some places. [Here is the complete list of Functions](http://viewmaster365.com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List) I collected that do work in SharePoint

Comment: Thanks for the link, good reference. But they do say that (like the MID function) is not supported, not that it doesn't work. EDIT : I think there is something to do with versions of SharePoint. In Standard 2013, MID function doesn't work...

Comment: I am a stupid dutchie, english is not my native language..   Not Supported === Not Usable  in my text book ;-)

Comment: Their description are sometimes unclear. I see the list as the basic formulas working with all versions. I don't know if more are available if you have Enterprise/Excel Services.

Comment: @Danny re-tested my stuff.... MID function works in SharePoint Standard 2013. Must have put semicolons instead of commas. Sorry for the confusion.Would be (not so) interesting to see if it works or not in Foundation.